# Hosting .Net Core app and Angular app under IIS Default website

Tags: angular, asp.net-core, iis, web-hosting, aspnetboilerplate

I'm using ASP.net core Boilerplate with angular.   I tried hosting both apps individually website for Angular and website for .NET core under IIS localhost with no problem.
:
But When I want to deploy my App on public I encountered this problem :
1- I have only one public IP which is redirecting to the IIS Default Website and each app has a different port.
**So, Both Front-end and Back-end should be hosted under the IIS Default Website with a different port.

### is that applicable with .NET core and Angular?**

**Update**

**And here is my appsetting.json**

```
{

  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "Default": "Server=localhost\\SQLEXPRESS; Database=MyDb;User Id=admin;Password=1234"
  },
  "App": {
    "ServerRootAddress": "http://localhost:21021/",
    "ClientRootAddress": "http://localhost:4200/",
    "CorsOrigins": "http://localhost:4200,http://localhost:8080,http://localhost:8081,http://localhost:3000"
  },
  "Authentication": {
    "JwtBearer": {
      "IsEnabled": "true",
      "SecurityKey": "MyApp_C421AAEE0D114E9C",
      "Issuer": "MyApp",
      "Audience": "MyApp"
    }
  }
}
```

**Update 2**

Angular web.config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <staticContent>
      <remove fileExtension=".json" />
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".json" mimeType="application/json" />
      <mimeMap fileExtension="woff" mimeType="application/font-woff" />
      <mimeMap fileExtension="woff2" mimeType="application/font-woff" />
    </staticContent>
    <!-- IIS URL Rewrite for Angular routes -->
    <rewrite>
      <rules>
        <rule name="Angular Routes" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url=".*" />
          <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
            <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="^/(api)" negate="true" />
          </conditions>
          <action type="Rewrite" url="/" />
        </rule>
      </rules>
    </rewrite>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Angular appconfig.production.json

```
{
  "remoteServiceBaseUrl": "http://localhost:21021",
  "appBaseUrl": "http://localhost:4200",
  "localeMappings": [
    {
      "from": "pt-BR",
      "to": "pt"
    },
    {
      "from": "zh-CN",
      "to": "zh"
    },
    {
      "from": "he-IL",
      "to": "he"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Even with a single IP address you can host multiple sites (different host names) at port 80. Stop the idea of using different ports as that only makes things complex.

Comment: @LexLi My public IP on Server x and I hosted the project on Server Y and my X server redirect the REquest to Y IIS server. I don't know why they did that but I can't change this scenario.

Comment: Then what do you have/install on server X? Usually people have a reverse proxy there, but you really need to learn what you have first. With a reverse proxy, you can do almost whatever you like (like https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/reverse-proxy-with-url-rewrite-v2-and-application-request-routing).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here are some steps:

Pre-requisite

Client Alias=> path name for client application which needed to add application in iis

Service Alias => path name for service application which needed to add application in iis

1. Download .NET Core 3.0 Runtime & Hosting Bundle for Windows or you can find exact version as per your project
   https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/dotnet-core/thank-you/runtime-aspnetcore-3.0.0-windows-hosting-bundle-installer
2. For the setup of Angular 8 infrastructure in Clinical Content Editor, installation of IIS extension "URL Rewrite” is required https://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite

Front End:

3. Build your angular run **ng build --prod --base-href=/client-alias/**
4. Go to Default Web Site in IIS
5. Add a application
6. Add Alias and point physical path to your **dist** folder in angular application
7. You can test this **http://localhost/client-alias**

   Back End (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/iis/?view=aspnetcore-3.1#create-the-iis-site)
8. Publish the API project and so that we can copy the content to the new web application of API Service.
9. Create an application pool with .net CLR version to **No Managed Code**
10. In IIS create a new web application for API Service with application pool added in step 9 and physical path of published folder as in step 8.

Now these two application are running on as http://127.0.0.1/client-alias and http://127.0.0.1/service-alias

You can make your IP(8080) public with no another port open.

Comment: thank you, Actually that what I exactly did, but I don't know what is the problem I think related to my app ports because default Backend app port is 21021 and 4200 for front-end and the Default website is 8080.

Comment: I have updated 1 thing. We can discuss in chat if that doesn't solve your issue

Comment: Thank you again, Actually, I did that before but with no luck, I think the problem in angular and .NET core app configuration, yes we can discuss that on chat but how could I open chat session in StackOverflow?

Comment: created https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/211613/room-for-gourav-garg-and-user3189162

Comment: Were you able to complete this?

Comment: Thank you but it didn't work, I used individual websites for each of FE and BE with similar IP with a different port.

Comment: the steps will work perfectly if I added reverse proxy configuration on IIS.

Answer (score 1):

Only your angular Website should be public. Every IIS Website need an unique port.
https://docs.aspnetzero.com/en/aspnet-core-angular/latest/Deployment-Angular-Publish-IIS

Also check out in your IIS Host Website the appSettings.json for

```
"App": {
    "ServerRootAddress": "http://localhost:21021/", -> Host 
    "ClientRootAddress": "http://localhost:4200/", -> Angular
    "CorsOrigins": "http://localhost:4200" -> your domain, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/cors?view=aspnetcore-3.1
```

},

If you have merged your Angular and Host Project:
https://aspnetboilerplate.com/Pages/Documents/Zero/Startup-Template-Angular#merged-project

Comment: Dear Dominik, Once I added my domain to the CorsOrigins the Front end stop working and after checking the log file I found CORS policy execution failed. also , regarding the first link actually I follow the steps but in my scenario, I can't create any website for My app what should I did is adding the both under IIS default website. regarding the second link actually I don't merge the solution I build each of them individually .